# Fixation of Random Matrix Theory on Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, random-matrices

Although "fixation" carries an unintended negative connotation, why does it seem like random matrix theory is focused so intently on the eigenvalues of the matrices in question? Why is so little discussion given on definitions for algebra operations for these matrices?

Of course, it is difficult to provide thorough evidence of this without extensive discussion but I will briefly try:

- In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Je4bU3g_QGk&t=2029s&ab_channel=ICTPCondensedMatterandStatisticalPhysics) titled "Random Matrices: Theory and Practice - Lecture 1", the lecturer states that random matrix theory is about saying "something" about the eigenvalues given joint distributions of matrix entries (around 3:00).
- In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06128.pdf) whose title seems primarily concerned the products of random matrices a substantial portion of the content is dedicated to matrix eigenvalues.
- More than half of the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix) on random matrices is concerned with distributions of their eigenvalues.

Does understanding the eigenvalues essentially "unlock" the ability to perform all other operations on these matrices? For example, can I find the expectation of the square of a random matrix without needing to find the distributions of its eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically speaking random matrices were introduced in physics, where eigenvalues show up naturally and have a physical meaning. Specifically, in the 1950's by Wigner. But beyond history, eigenvalues just appear all over the place in real world applications. And finally, eigenvalues are also interesting for purely aesthetical reasons as well; as Higham and Embree put it, "They give a matrix a personality".

As for why "algebra operations" are ignored, you might need to be more specific about what you think is being ignored and in what context it comes up. The concrete question you asked, "can I find the expectation of the square of a random matrix without needing to find the distributions of its eigenvalues?", is yes by just squaring the matrix and then computing the expected values of it's entries. I think a lot of the "algebra operations" you are talking about might be found in texts about multivariate analysis.